# Can't retrive full path to file by ProcessID in kernel driver

Tags: windows, kernel, driver

I need to obtain full path to file by PID. I had tried many ways but all of them causing BSOD or returning some error.
This is my code that causing BSOD:

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessImagePath(HANDLE hProcess, PUNICODE_STRING pImagePath) {
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE hProcessObj = NULL;

    // Open a handle to the process.
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttr;
    CLIENT_ID clientId;

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&objAttr, NULL, OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);
    clientId.UniqueProcess = (HANDLE)hProcess;
    clientId.UniqueThread = 0;
    status = ZwOpenProcess(&hProcessObj, 0x0400 | 0x0010, &objAttr, &clientId);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DbgPrint(L"Failed to ZwOpenProcess");
        return status;
    }

    WCHAR wzImagePath[260] = { 0 };
    ULONG ulLength = 0;
    status = ZwQueryInformationProcessPtr(hProcessObj, ProcessImageFileName, wzImagePath, sizeof(wzImagePath), &ulLength);

    // Copy the result to the output buffer.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        DbgPrint(L"Failed to ZwQueryInformationProcessPtr");
        return status; 
    }

    UNICODE_STRING uImagePath;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uImagePath, wzImagePath);
    RtlCopyUnicodeString(pImagePath, &uImagePath);

    ZwClose(hProcessObj);

    return status;
}
```

I'm passing PID from user-mode application. Also, I have to mention that `ZwQueryInformationProcessPtr` is dynamically loaded function, because I didn't find it in `wdm.h` or `ntifs.h`.

I'm loading it like this:

```
    UNICODE_STRING functionName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"ZwQueryInformationProcess");
    ZwQueryInformationProcessPtr = (pfnZwQueryInformationProcess)MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&functionName);
    if (!ZwQueryInformationProcessPtr) {
        DbgPrint("Failed to load ZwQueryInformationProcess!");
        return STATUS_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    else {
        DbgPrint("Successfully loaded ZwQueryInformationProcess!");
    }
```

When a driver starts, I see that it's loading correctly!
Here is example how I'm calling `GetProcessImagePath`

```
            UNICODE_STRING filePath;
            NTSTATUS status = GetProcessImagePath((HANDLE)RequestTerminate->ProcessId, &filePath);
            if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
                DbgPrint(L"Failed to retrive filepath for %d", RequestTerminate->ProcessId);
            }
```

What's wrong with `GetProcessImagePath`?

Comment: `ZwQueryInformationProcess(ProcessImageFileName)` retreives a `UNICODE_STRING`, not a `WCHAR` buffer. Also, `RtlCopyUnicodeString()` requires the destination `UNICODE_STRING` to be appropriately initialized. For these types of APIs the general pattern is to call it once to get the size needed, allocate a large enough buffer, then call it again; in this case you could return the allocated buffer to the caller.